# Hyperledger fabric sample balance-transfer giving error while trying to join the channel

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

[ERROR] Join-Channel - TypeError: client.getEventHubsForOrg is not a function
        at Object.joinChannel (/home/shashankp/projects/Block-Chain/samples/fabric-samples/balance-transfer/app/join-channel.js:54:27)
        at 
        at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7)
    enter code here

curl -s -X POST \
      http://localhost:4000/channels/mychannel/peers \
      -H "authorization: Bearer $ORG1_TOKEN" \
      -H "content-type: application/json" \
      -d '{
        "peers": ["peer0.org1.example.com","peer1.org1.example.com"]
    }'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updated fabric-client and fabric-ca-client to 1.2.1 resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Method `getEventHubsForOrg` has been deprecated by Official, If you are using the newest fabric sdk (check your `package.json` to see which version you're installed), you should use `channel.getChannelEventHubsForOrg` insteaded.

Or you can degrade your SDK version to 1.0.* to try if farbic-sample supports.

Check https://fabric-sdk-node.github.io/Channel.html#getChannelEventHubsForOrg__anchor for more detail.